# Which ns2 protocol is the most practical to use

Tags: awk, ns2

My trace file on AODV is more than 1GB.  My problem is which protocol I should use: AODV or DSR or DSDV or....

Since my scenario has about 300 nodes with 3 mobile nodes.  I am getting too much difficulties while writing awk scripts to get the matrix evaluation for my scenario.

Comment: Not clear, please do add more details with samples and let us know then.

Comment: »»which protocol«« : Create copies of AODV-name.tcl → {dsr-name.tcl, dsdv-name.tcl}, edit to new routeprotocols DSR, DSDV and run simulations. .... Too large trace: Set a stop : See tcl/ex/simple-wireless.tcl, line 139 → `$ns_ at 150.01 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"` + lines above .... and use a shorter time.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I did till now 3 copies with the same code and the only difference is the used protocol. My problem is how could I be sure of which copy should I use to apply the awk script? I am working on reducing energy comsuption

Comment: Edit the trace.tr in the three simulatios to respectively aodv-out.tr, dsdv-out.tr, dsr-out.tr ... and run your awk -f commands , to see energy results. .... ~ **240** awk scripts https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rU_MFAEl1GCLMTJPLR3zbxPxkQQHkQ7T?usp=sharing

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 To be more precise, which types of events should I use in my awk script? I have selected event N which didn't give me the right average of energy at time t

Comment: @moe assal : Please read the "top 20 scripts" in ns2 APP-Tool/Final/ https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool